Interacting with Okular (backward search)
I use Auctex to edit my LaTeX files. I've configured Auctex to use Okular as my PDF viewer, and I've configured Okular to use Emacs (emacsclient) as its editor.
When I compile a source file with C-c C-a Okular gets the focus and shows me the pdf page corresponding to the point in Emacs. Also, if I change the point position in Emacs and use "Quick View" (C-c C-v) Okular shows me the corresponding PDF page. So far, so good.
If I continue reading the PDF in Okular and I spot an error, a few pages later, when I go back to Emacs giving focus to it the point is not moved and I have to scroll, or use C-s, to go to the position where I can correct my mistake.
Is there a particular way of focusing Emacs that moves the point to the new position in the PDF?

I have to add that the so called manual of Okular has a section "Inverse Search between LATEX Editors and Okular" but when you go there, you'll read

There is no documentation available for /inverse_search.html.


CLOSING
After a system update the help browser shows the contents of "Inverse Search between LATEX Editors and Okular", and Shift-mouse1 moves Emacs'point in the correct position.
This works only in "Browse" mode, that is the default mode of Okular.
I'll close my question, my apologies for the noise.

I'm trying to picture what you've described. Maybe you could add a .gif to make your question clearer.

Maybe I'm getting this wrong, but do you expect that Emacs follows where you are in Okular when you're viewing your .pdf?  Usually, the inverse search works by clicking the place in the .pdf file, accompanied with shift or other keys, depending on the viewer.  Try shift + left mouse click in Okular and see if you jump in Emacs to that place.

@ArashEsbati Exactly, I want to jump from a position in the PDF file, open in Okular, to the corresponding position in the source file, open in Emacs. And I know it's more a question about Okular than a question about Emacs, but…

@gboffi - I don't use Okular, so I can't really help.  But have you configured Okular for inverse search?  It seems it can already deal with Emacs.

@ArashEsbati In the last week I've repeatedly tried different mouse clicks with different modifiers, comprising Shift Mouse-1 to no avail, but today Shift Mouse-1is working as expected. Yesterday night I've updated my system, who knows... I'll close my question, thank you for the help and the support.

I’m voting to close this question because OP asked to close it.
